# Drupal 6: can I pass variables to a node template by function call, not just by preprocess functions?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'm working on a site for which I happen to need to embed the entire output of a node template (for a couple of content types) into various other templates.  Most of the cases are embedding a node - selected in a nodereference CCK field - into a view template, so my current approach is:

- in the view settings: add the noderef field directly as one of the fields to output (as opposed to using a relationship to make the referenced node's fields accessible)
- set the format for field output to "full node" - which I've found prints the whole node template

This is great, BUT: there are a few important variables that are used in the node template. The only way I already know of to set these is via a preprocess function, which does work... The annoyance with this method is that in the preprocess function I have to detect (by whatever is accessible there) where the template output will be embedded, so I can set the variables appropriately.

**What I want to do instead:**

Intuitively, it'd make way more sense to be able to call a function in my various view templates that would: a) allow me to print the whole node template, and b) pass in values for the preprocess variables. Does anyone know a function that can do this, or an alternate method?

[Thoughts so far that haven't gotten me anywhere:

I know in similar cases, you can pass in options as arguments to theme(), according to the signature of the particular theme function that will be called. But [node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view/6) does not provide that ability -- and node_view() seems to be the proper function to call for invoking the node template, rather than theme('node', ...).

I see that node_view() invokes hook_nodeapi() with 'alter' as $op, but that is happening too late in the game; the node content will already be in HTML format by then (i.e. $node->body).]

Comment: It sounds like you agree that this feels wrong. . . I'd like to know more about what the page is and how the nodes relate so that we can help you come up with a more streamlined solution.

Comment: @mirzu We have a content type that acts as a wrapper for several possible sources (as different CCK fields) of images. The node template for this type runs through a cascade, checking which source field is filled in, and also handles image sizing. The image sizing and a couple other options are handled with the preprocess variables. So, a number of other content types have the noderef field pointing to one of these image nodes; hence the need for embedding image nodes' full template output.

Comment: perhaps it would be easier to abstract out the resizing into functions that are just in a module, and then calling those functions in the preprocess for either this view or the node it's self.

Comment: @mirzu yeah, that method would feel better to me too, but unfortunately the resizing is handled differently - sometimes even externally - depending on which source the image is coming from... (I always wonder how people get into odd use case scenarios when I read forums.. and here I am, in one myself!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is hook_nodeapi($op = 'view'), if you want to change existing elements, you give your module a high weight so that it is called last. To know *when* you want to customize something, you could set a custom flag on the node object, something like `$node->yourmodule_inside_view_noderef = TRUE` before you pass it to node_view().

In Drupal 7, there is the so called $view_mode concept instead of just a boolean flag to show the teaser or not.

You can define your own view_modes through [hook_entity_info()](http://api.drupal.org/hook_entity_info), here is an example from userpoints_nodeaccess: [userpoints_nodeaccess_entity_info](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/userpoints/userpoints_nodeaccess-7.x-1.x--userpoints_nodeaccess.module/function/userpoints_nodeaccess_entity_info/7-1). This allows you to react based on the view_mode in hook_node_view/hook_node_view_alter but also allows you to customize which fields should be displayed how and which view_mode should be used when the node is displayed without needing custom code.

Comment: Actually, attaching a custom flag on $node might be all I need. Process that comes to mind: nid in view template -> node_load() it -> store the flag according to context -> preprocess function sets variables based on flags (and probably unsets flags to avoid conflicts). Then I don't even need hook_nodeapi().

This works in my head - will try soon and accept answer if it goes well. Thank you!

Comment: Final solution: nid in view template -> node_load() it -> store an array of options to $node with keys matching the preprocess var names -> in preprocess function, array_merge() this option array with $vars -> unset the options array to clean up $node. Awesome thinking and thank you, @Berdir. (Btw, I'm still fully entrenched in developing w/Drupal 6, so haven't looked into Drupal 7 yet, but the view_mode idea sounds like a good one.)